# Importing Fields into Field Editor - how?

Tags: add-on, ee2, custom-fields, how-to

I've got [Field Editor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-editor) installed on a new site that I would like to copy/clone fields from an existing site I've built. In the Field Editor CP there's an option to import a field group with a file. This is fantastic, but I can't for the life of me find where to export a field group from an existing site.

The [docs for field editor](http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/field-editor/) are rather sparse and not helpful in this case.

So is there a way to export field groups from one site to a file and then use field editor to import them into a new site?

New site EE 2.5.3 existing site EE 2.2.2 but scheduled for upgrade to 2.5.3 in the next day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export one field group at a time in Field Editor while in it's "homepage."

[image: Field Editor Export]

Comment: So I have to have field editor installed on both sites...

Comment: Yes, EE core doesn't come with a custom field group/custom field import/export.

Comment: I know what your next question is: "do I have to buy two copies of Field Editor?" and I'd say YES though, you'd have to ask the developer to verify that to be the case or not.

Comment: Thanks Nate - will upgrade the old site and then export field group.